# C++ vector assignments

Tags: c++, vector, calculator, assignment-operator

My program should read input as an integer for the length followed by (sufficiently) parenthesized floats and simple operators and output the value of the expression. For example, if the input were `11  1 + 2 ^ 3 / 4 * 5 - 6`, the result should be equal to `(1 + (((2 ^ 3) / 4) * 5)) - 6`, or 5. However, even when I input `5  1 + 2 + 3`, the output is 5 instead of 6. I think this might be because of the many vector assignments, in particular the marked line (I found this while debugging).

My code (sorry if it is not self explanatory):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

float op(char op, float x, float y)
{
    switch (op)
    {
        case '+':
        {
            return x+y;
            break;
        }
        case '-':
        {
            return x-y;
            break;
        }
        case '*':
        {
            return x*y;
            break;
        }
        case '/':
        {
            return x/y;
            break;
        }
        case '^':
        {
            return pow(x,y);
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            cout << "Error: bad input ";
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

float nopars(vector<string> stack, int stackl, vector<char> ops, int opsr)
{
    int len = stackl, opsrr = opsr;
    vector<string> nstack, nnstack;
    vector<char> nops = ops, nnops;
    nstack = stack;
    while (opsrr != 0)
    {
        string s1 (1, nops[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            if (nstack[i] == s1)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < len - 2; j++)
                {
                    nnstack = {};
                    if (j == i-1)
                    {
                        nnstack.push_back(to_string(op(nops[0], stof(nstack[i-1]), stof(nstack[i+1]))));
                    }
                    else if (j < i-1)
                    {
                        nnstack.push_back(nstack[j]);
                    }
                    else if (j > i-1)
                    {
                        nnstack.push_back(nstack[j+2]);
                    }
                }
                len = len - 2;
                nstack = nnstack;                                   //I think this is wrong? 
                i--;
            }
        }
        nnops = {};
        for (int i = 0; i < opsr-1; i++)
        {
            nnops.push_back(nops[i+1]);
        }
        opsrr--;
        nops = nnops;
    }
    return stof(nstack[0]);
}

float all(vector<string> stack, int stackl, vector<char> ops, int opsr)
{
    int t1 = 0, t2 = 0;
    int len = stackl;
    int nprs;
    vector<string> nstack, nnstack, nstck;
    nstack = stack;
    while (true)
    {
        nprs = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            if (nstack[i] == "(")
            {
                nprs = 1;
                t1 = i;
            }
            else if (nstack[i] == ")")
            {
                nprs = 1;
                t2 = i;
                nstck = {};
                for (int j = t1 + 1; j < t2; j++)
                {
                    nstck.push_back(nstack[j]);
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < len - t2 + t1; j++)
                {
                    if (j == t1)
                    {
                        nnstack.push_back(to_string(nopars(nstck, t2-t1-1, ops, opsr)));
                    }
                    else if (j < t1)
                    {
                        nnstack.push_back(nstack[j]);
                    }
                    else if (j > t1)
                    {
                        nnstack.push_back(nstack[j+t2-t1]);
                    }
                }
                len = len - t2 + t1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (nprs == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        nstack = nnstack;
    }
    return nopars(nstack, len, ops, opsr);
}

void calculate()
{
    vector<string> stack;
    int stackl;
    string t;
    cin >> stackl;
    for (int i = 0; i < stackl; i++)
    {
        cin >> t;
        stack.push_back(t);
    }
    cout << all(stack, stackl, {'^', '/', '*', '-', '+'}, 5);
}

int main()
{
    calculate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, naming a vector as stack. That is pure evil

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 I use Xcode, but there was no compiler error. However, the program messes up at that line (I inserted some cout lines to find that). Also, the vector was named a stack because I wrote the program recursively, so that I needed to keep track of a stack of numbers.

Comment: I don't know how to use the Xcode debugger, let alone how to make it find the error (which is not a typo but a logical problem).

Comment: Its time you learnt that now. Go on to the official doc and take a look. You need to understand that if your code does anything more than adding 2 numbers, you might need a debugger to figure out the problem. Debugger is a programmer's best friend and will help you throughout

Comment: @littlecat -- You really shouldn't write all of this code and not be able to use the debugger.  The debugger allows you to single-step a line at a time in your code, watch variables, see if the program flow is correct, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for the explanation. I have just tried the debugger in Xcode. It seems that the information in it is precisely the set of variables and other data at a specific time. This was really helpful for finding the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A binary recurrent LL parser

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <cmath>
#include <map>

using namespace std;
using T = float;

map< int, map<std::string, std::function<T(const T&, const T&)> > > m_foo = 
    { {1, { { "+", std::plus<T>() }, { "-", std::minus<T>() }  } },
      {2, { { "*", std::multiplies<T>() }, { "/", std::divides<T>() } } },
      {3, { { "^", powf } } } };

T calc_ll(istream_iterator<string>& t, int level) {
   if ( !m_foo.contains(level) ) return  std::stof(*t++);

   auto result = calc_ll(t, level+1);
   auto l = m_foo[level];
   while ( l.find(*t) != l.end() ) {
      auto foo = l.find(*t)->second; 
      result = foo(result, calc_ll(++t, level+1) );
   }
   return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss(std::string("1 + 2 ^ 3 / 4 * 5 - 6"));
    auto t = istream_iterator<string>(ss);
    cout << "result : " << calc_ll( t, 1 );
    return 0;
}
```

link https://godbolt.org/z/9vPMGn

Answer (score 0):

It seems the error is in the unintentionally repeated declaration `nnstack = {}`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

float op(char op, float x, float y)
{
    switch (op)
    {
        case '+':
        {
            return x+y;
            break;
        }
        case '-':
        {
            return x-y;
            break;
        }
        case '*':
        {
            return x*y;
            break;
        }
        case '/':
        {
            return x/y;
            break;
        }
        case '^':
        {
            return pow(x,y);
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            cout << "Error: bad input ";
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

float nopars(vector<string> stack, int stackl, vector<char> ops, int opsr)
{
    int len = stackl, opsrr = opsr;
    vector<string> nstack, nnstack;
    vector<char> nops = ops, nnops;
    nstack = stack;
    while (opsrr != 0)
    {
        string s1 (1, nops[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            if (nstack[i] == s1)
            {
                nnstack = {};                              //this was missing
                for (int j = 0; j < len - 2; j++)
                {
                    //nnstack = {};                        //this was misplaced
                    if (j == i-1)
                    {
                        nnstack.push_back(to_string(op(nops[0], stof(nstack[i-1]), stof(nstack[i+1]))));
                    }
                    else if (j < i-1)
                    {
                        nnstack.push_back(nstack[j]);
                    }
                    else if (j > i-1)
                    {
                        nnstack.push_back(nstack[j+2]);
                    }
                }
                len = len - 2;
                nstack = nnstack;
                i--;
            }
        }
        nnops = {};
        for (int i = 0; i < opsr-1; i++)
        {
            nnops.push_back(nops[i+1]);
        }
        opsrr--;
        nops = nnops;
    }
    return stof(nstack[0]);
}

float all(vector<string> stack, int stackl, vector<char> ops, int opsr)
{
    int t1 = 0, t2 = 0;
    int len = stackl;
    int nprs;
    vector<string> nstack, nnstack, nstck;
    nstack = stack;
    while (true)
    {
        nprs = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            if (nstack[i] == "(")
            {
                nprs = 1;
                t1 = i;
            }
            else if (nstack[i] == ")")
            {
                nprs = 1;
                t2 = i;
                nstck = {};
                for (int j = t1 + 1; j < t2; j++)
                {
                    nstck.push_back(nstack[j]);
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < len - t2 + t1; j++)
                {
                    if (j == t1)
                    {
                        nnstack.push_back(to_string(nopars(nstck, t2-t1-1, ops, opsr)));
                    }
                    else if (j < t1)
                    {
                        nnstack.push_back(nstack[j]);
                    }
                    else if (j > t1)
                    {
                        nnstack.push_back(nstack[j+t2-t1]);
                    }
                }
                len = len - t2 + t1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (nprs == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        nstack = nnstack;
    }
    return nopars(nstack, len, ops, opsr);
}

void calculate()
{
    vector<string> stack;
    int stackl;
    string t;
    cin >> stackl;
    for (int i = 0; i < stackl; i++)
    {
        cin >> t;
        stack.push_back(t);
    }
    cout << all(stack, stackl, {'^', '/', '*', '-', '+'}, 5);
}

int main()
{
    calculate();
    return 0;
}
```